# Set custom page numbers for org-mode pdf export

Tags: org-mode, org-export

Is it possible to set the page numbers for a pdf in org mode? I need the title and contents page to be labelled as roman numerals and then the main body of the document to start at page 1.

Anyone know how I can easily do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answered by /u/thblt on reddit:

Adding `#+LATEX_HEADER: \pagenumbering{roman}` to the top of the document and then `#+LATEX: \pagenumbering{arabic}` before the main body of the document solves this perfectly.